# Radio button selection creates a dynamic drop down list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a drop down list that is dynamically populated depending on what selection is made in a group of radio buttons. I currently have a group of radio buttons names "Applicability" and the options to select are: People, Procedure, Environment, Capability to deliver, Technical Airworthiness and Operational Airworthiness. Depending on which one is selected, I would like the drop down box to populate with a number of options to select.   The code I am working with at the moment is:

```
var peList = [“Worker Type”, “Injury Type”];
var enList = [“Undefined”];
var prList = ["Facility", "Building", "Plant", "Damage Type"];
var caList = ["To Be Determined"];
var teList = ["Aircraft", "Component"];
var opList = ["Nothing at the moment"];

if (Applicability.rawValue===”People”) {
           DropDownList4.clearItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < peList.length; i++) { 
        DropDownList4.addItem(peList[i]);
}
        } else if (Applicability.rawValue===”Property”) {
           DropDownList4.clearItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < prList.length; i++) { 
        DropDownList4.addItem(prList[i]);
        }
        } else if (Applicability.rawValue===”Environment”) {
           DropDownList4.clearItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < enList.length; i++) { 
        DropDownList4.addItem(enList[i]);
        }
        } else if (Applicability.rawValue===”CapabilityToDeliver”) {
           DropDownList4.clearItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < caList.length; i++) { 
        DropDownList4.addItem(caList[i]);
        }
        } else if (Applicability.rawValue===”TechnicalAirworthiness”) {
           DropDownList4.clearItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < taList.length; i++) { 
        DropDownList4.addItem(taList[i]);
        }
        } else if (Applicability.rawValue===”OperationalAirworthiness”) {
           DropDownList4.clearItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < opList.length; i++) { 
        DropDownList4.addItem(opList[i]);}
```

Can you please assist by showing me where I might be going wrong? Thank you

Comment: Are you getting an error somewhere? The code looks ok to me

Comment: Thanks! It's not producing an error, its just not working. I thought it it might have been a case of not selecting the correct execute option. I've tried 'click' and 'initalise' but neither work. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

clearitems is a method and should be called as DropDownList4.clearItems(); Note the parenthesis here that are missing in your code.
Also, make the code much more maintainable by using switch. For example:

```
var a,al,ax; // array, array length, array index
switch(Applicability.rawValue){
case 'People': a=['Worker Type', 'Injury Type'];break;
case 'Property': a=['Facility', 'Building', 'Plant', 'Damage Type'];break;
case 'Environment': a=['Undefined'];break;
case 'CapabilityToDeliver': a=['To Be Determined'];break;
case 'TechnicalAirworthiness': a=['Aircraft', 'Component'];break;
case 'OperationalAirworthiness': a=['Nothing at the moment'];break;
default:
 // put your exception handling code here.
}
DropDownList4.clearItems();
for(ax=0,al=a.length;ax<al;ax++){ 
 DropDownList4.addItem(a[ax]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! To be honest, the code I gave was developed by another and I couldn't get it to work. What do you mean by "// Put your exception hadling code here" ?  Also, I know this has to be entered as javascript, however I'm not sure I'm using the correct execute botton. Should I use 'click' or 'initialise'? Thank you so much!

Comment: // tells javascript to ignore everything from that point to the end of the line. So we use that to write messages that JS will ignore but humans won't.

Comment: In normal operation the rawValue will always be one of the six cases. But what if it is not? What if you  misspelled property?  You could replace that // line with alert('There is a mistake in the code. I do not know what to do with a value of '+Applicability.rawValue);  Then, if something was misspelled someone would see the message, tell you about it and you would fix it. The alert would handle the "exceptions", the things that should never happen.